# remotely copy from Windows source by running scp on Linux

Tags: ssh

I want to copy files remotely in a script from windows machine to Linux machine.
On the Linux machine I run the below command

```
scp user@remotehost:\D\mySrcCode\somefile.cpp .
```

I am getting an error

```
scp: DmySrcCodesomefile.cpp: No such file or directory
```

The file somefile.cpp is located at D:\mySrcCode on windows side.

Any ideas on what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should quote or backslash the backslashes in the path.

If your interactive shell is GNU bash, read its [§3.1.2 quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting) chapter.

You could try:

```
 scp user@remotehost:\\D\\mySrcCode\\somefile.cpp .
```

Consider also using other (more appropriate) tools, like [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) or [git](https://git-scm.com/).

You might also use [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) from your C program to run  `/usr/bin/ssh`, or look into [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/).

You could change your login shell (see [chsh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) and `/etc/shells` so [shells(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html)) to more user friendly alternatives such as [zsh](https://zsh.org/) or [fish](https://fishshell.com/). They could give you some warning (depending on how they are configured or used) or some autocompletion (with the <kbd>tab</kbd>key).

PS. Your problem is not `ssh` specific. You might replace `scp` with `echo` to understand it more.